# Problem with VMware Workstation 12. on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, vmware

[kenneth@kyb0rg ~]$ uname -r
4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64

When I start VMWare a box appears!
[image]

I click install

[image]

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log for details.

`[root@kyb0rg kenneth]# /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log
bash: /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log: Permission denied
[root@kyb0rg kenneth]# open /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log
[root@kyb0rg kenneth]# cat /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=14992 version=12.1.1 build=build-3770994 option=Release
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64 Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.140-05:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.155-05:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-14992.log
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64 to "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.159-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.165-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.165-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.275-05:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers
2016-09-11T11:32:52.275-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 17372 symbol versions
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.290-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.292-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.292-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.293-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.293-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.294-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.294-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.296-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.296-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.298-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.306-05:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2016-09-11T11:32:52.306-05:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64 to "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.315-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.321-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.321-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.431-05:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers
2016-09-11T11:32:52.431-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.445-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 17372 symbol versions
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.446-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.451-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.451-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.452-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2016-09-11T11:32:52.454-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.3.1".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.454-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.454-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.457-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.3.1".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.457-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.458-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.464-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.464-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.465-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.465-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.465-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.465-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.465-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.470-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.470-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.470-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64 to "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.471-05:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2016-09-11T11:32:52.476-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.476-05:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include" for the kernel "4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2016-09-11T11:32:52.586-05:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers
2016-09-11T11:32:52.586-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/Module.symvers.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.600-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 17372 symbol versions
2016-09-11T11:32:52.600-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.602-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.602-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.604-05:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.692-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/misc/vmmon.ko".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.692-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2016-09-11T11:32:52.699-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2016-09-11T11:32:52.699-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-gLvcSL/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-09-11T11:32:54.104-05:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-09-11T11:32:54.105-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/misc/vmnet.ko".
2016-09-11T11:32:54.105-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2016-09-11T11:32:54.108-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2016-09-11T11:32:54.108-05:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-gLvcSL/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2016-09-11T11:32:55.414-05:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.`

Comment: It looks like it complains several times about `version.h` missing. I'd try to get that file first and then try again. Or, there are a few posts about the error `failed to build vmnet`, such as this one here, which might be able to help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/414783/unable-to-run-vmware-failed-to-build-vmnet

Comment: Follow the directions here: http://vcojot.blogspot.com/2015/11/vmware-worksation-12-on-fedora-core-23.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem myself, it involves the module sources for **vmmon** and **vmnet** which do not compile on Linux kernels **4.7 and later** without modification. The solution came from the ArchWiki but is applicable to many distros. I have not tested this on Fedora, only Debian, but it should work regardless:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#Kernel_modules_fail_to_build_after_Linux_4.7

You may need to use **sudo** for some commands. First update the **vmmon** source:

1. cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
2. tar xf vmmon.tar
3. mv vmmon .tar vmmon.old.tar
4. sed -r -i -e 's/get_user_pages(_remote)*/get_user_pages_remote/g' vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
5. tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
6. rm -r vmmon-only

Now do the same for **vmnet**. Skip step 1 if you are already in the  **/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source** directory:

1. cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
2. tar xf vmnet.tar
3. mv vmnet.tar vmnet.old.tar
4. sed -r -i -e 's/get_user_pages(_remote)*/get_user_pages_remote/g' vmnet-only/userif.c
5. sed -i -e 's/dev->trans_start = jiffies/netif_trans_update(dev)/g' vmnet-only/netif.c
6. tar cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
7. rm -r vmnet-only

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1 note at step2: there is a space between vmmon and .tar causing a command execution error

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a fresh one:
I have been running the patched vmnet version for a while, after the last FC23 kernel update (to 4.7.2-101.fc23.x86_64) vmnet make fails with this error:

netif.c:468:7: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'trans_start'

see http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=1746 for a discussion.

Comment: As stated in the discussion, opening vmnet.tar and updating `dev->trans_start = jiffies;` to `netif_trans_update(dev);` allowed vmnet to compile. I had already patched the vmmon/vmnet code once for FC24 and re-linked some libraries under `/usr/lib/vmware/lib`. The VM failed to connect to the network. I upgraded to Workstation 12.5 and re-applied these patches. It seems to be working. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

tar xf vmmon.tar

tar xf vmnet.tar

cd vmmon-only

make

cd ../vmnet

make

cd ..

mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc

cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko

cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko

depmod -a

/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

> Everytime there's a New build You have to go through the
>   steps again.

Answer (score -2):

I had same, try

```
dnf update 
reboot
```